# how to avoid nested for loop to solve below problem

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class job
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string JobNumber { get; set; }
        public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    }  

 public class attachment
    {
        public string JobNumber { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }

    }

        List<job> joblist = new List<job>();
        List<attachment> attachments = new List<attachment>();

        for (int i = 0; i < joblist.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < attachments.Count; j++)
            {
                if(joblist[i].JobNumber == attachments[j].JobNumber)
                {
                    joblist[i].IsValid = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

If both joblist and attachment list class has same jobnumber we make it valid
 is there any way to improve this code using linq

Comment: LINQ is for _querying_ conceisely, not for updating or execution efficiency. You could use Linq to make more concise code, but a properly written `for` loop will always be more efficient. You could also create a `HashSet` of the `attachment.JobNumber`s and do the lookup in linear time, but the overhead of creating the `HashSet` would only be worthwhile if you use the same attachment `List` a lot, or have a very long `List`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8) to find an attachment with a corresponding `JobNumber`:

```
foreach (var j in joblist)
{
    j.IsValid = attachments.Any(a => a.JobNumber == j.JobNumber);
}
```

Keep in mind this is still a *(worst case)* O(n²) operation, though on average slightly more efficient than your original code, because your loop did not `break` after finding a match.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `HashSet`, you can optimize the test for having an attachment to be O(1), but the overhead of creating the `HashSet` would only be worthwhile if you have a very long list of attachments or a very long list of jobs, or use the same attachment list with lots of different job lists:

```
var HasAttachment = attachments.Select(a => a.JobNumber).ToHashSet();

for (int i = 0; i < joblist.Count; i++) {
    joblist[i].IsValid = HasAttachment.Contains(joblist[i].JobNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pure LINQ, but you could trade `joblist.Count` enumerations of the inner loop and remove it entirely for one enumeration of `attachments`...

```cs
HashSet<string> attachmentJobNumbers = new HashSet<string>(
    // A one-time enumeration of attachments to collect its JobNumber values
    attachments.Select(attachment => attachment.JobNumber)
);

for (int i = 0; i < joblist.Count; i++)
{
    joblist[i].IsValid = attachmentJobNumbers.Contains(joblist[i].JobNumber);
}
```

The [`HashSet<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1) allows fast lookups of whether there is any attachment with a particular `JobNumber`.  This assumes that there are no equivalent `JobNumber` values that differ only by case; otherwise, you can pass a [`StringComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer) to an overload of the `HashSet<>` constructor...

```cs
HashSet<string> attachmentJobNumbers = new HashSet<string>(
    // A one-time enumeration of attachments to collect its JobNumber values
    attachments.Select(attachment => attachment.JobNumber),
    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase
);
```

...to get case-insensitive lookups.

(From [@NetMage's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60660237/150605) I learn that a [`ToHashSet()` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tohashset) has been around since .NET 4.7.2/.NET Core 2.0, so that would be a convenient alternative.)

A pure LINQ way to do the same thing would be with [`ToDictionary()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary)...

```cs
// A one-time enumeration of attachments to collect its JobNumber values
Dictionary<string, attachment> attachmentsByJobNumber = attachments.ToDictionary(attachment => attachment.JobNumber);

for (int i = 0; i < joblist.Count; i++)
{
    joblist[i].IsValid = attachmentsByJobNumber.ContainsKey(joblist[i].JobNumber);
}
```

...or [`ToLookup()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup), although either allows you to get an `attachment` by its `JobNumber` when the `attachment` isn't needed here, just a `bool`ean answer to "Is there any attachment with this `JobNumber` or not?".  I think `HashSet<>` would better represent this use case.

Also, keep in mind that .NET's [naming guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines) call for [types](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces) and [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members#names-of-properties) to use Pascal case, so you should use `Job`, `Attachment`, and `Id` (or possibly `ID`), respectively.